# How to put margin between the floated elements and cleared element?

Tags: css

I have an html with floated boxes and no contents and a sample footer positioned at the bottom. The problem is I can't provide a margin between the container of the boxes and the footer.

```css
#main {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  width: 46.6668%;
  padding-bottom: 46.6668%;
  margin: 1.6666%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

I added another div to act as a margin between these two, setting its height equal to the desired margin (eg. 200px). The new html and added css codes will now look like

```css
#main {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  width: 46.6668%;
  padding-bottom: 46.6668%;
  margin: 1.6666%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#space {
  clear: both;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="space"></div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Is this appropriate?

Comment: *Is this appropriate?* --> does it work? if yes then it's appropriate

Comment: I wonder if this is the best possible solution

Comment: there is no *best* solution. There is *working code as intended* or *not working code*. Best is opinion based and for me the best solution is to get rid of float and consider Flexbox or CSS grid but this is only my opinion.

Comment: if you want minor space like (50px to 100px) between boxes and container use margin top on #footer or margin-bottom on #main but you want more space like (200px to 500px) than it appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your floats using the `::after` pseudo on your parent container like this `#main::after {content: '';display: table;clear: both;}`

```css
#main {
max-width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#main::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.box
{
width: 46.6668%;
padding-bottom: 46.6668%;
margin: 1.6666%;
background-color: black;
float: left;
}

#footer
{
clear: both;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
background-color: gray;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The clearfix technique is my preferred solution, although I often use an older variant of it

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the `div.#main` is not taking up the height of its child elements. Just add:

```
#main {
  /*Keep your applied style*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now if you add `margin-top` to `#footer` or `margin-bottom` to `#main`, it should work.
Hope it helps. Cheers!